# How to receive sms on my ios app (workaround)?

Tags: ios, sms, message

I know i can't access the sms database of a ios device, but there's no workaround to achieve the same task using other tools?

My app must send an sms (which i do presenting the regular view of the ui message framework and asking the user to send it) and then receive a reply sms.
There's no way to receive this sms? There are online service or whatever can help me to do this?

Comment: [APNs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Push_Notification_Service) is a feature intended for receiving remote messages, but intercepting SMS messages is not permitted.

Comment: As Justin said, in no possible way I can imagine anyone letting an application intercept their text messages.

Comment: Yes, i know that is not permitted, that's why i specified it in the first line of my question. I was guessing if there'a way to do it in a alternative way, for the system that reply to my sms is a black box to me and the only thing it can do is sending sms. Maybe i can send the sms to some sort of online service and retrieve the result in the app, for example. I was indeed searching for some sort of workaround.

Comment: Truly, i do not want to access user sms, but only to exchange information with the outer world. Informations that the user needs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the situation has not changed in recent years: there is no way to read any SMS (except if you're on a jailbroken device).

But one thing you *can* do is embed an URL in your reply SMS that the user needs to tap. You can then use an URL handler in your app to handle these. Like:

```
myapp://smsreceived?id=123&result=456
```

There's plenty of documentation on how to implement URL handlers.

Comment: This is interesting. I'm searching for something like this